# How to display a line break <br> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display some infos in a `div` separated by `<br>` using javascript. Example just html:

```
<div id="adresscontent">
        Street number
        <br>
        city postalcode
        <br>
        country
  </div>
```

Now I want to display the same things with javascript. How can I solve the problem with the `<br>`?
My code right now:

```
 var street = response[i].street;
                    var house_number = response[i].house_number;
                    var city = response[i].city;
                    var postcode = response[i].postcode;
                    var country = response[i].country;
                    document.getElementById("adresscontent").innerHTML = street + " " + house_number + " " + city + " " + postcode + " "  + country  ;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `<br>`

```
var street = response[i].street;
                    var house_number = response[i].house_number;
                    var city = response[i].city;
                    var postcode = response[i].postcode;
                    var country = response[i].country;
                    document.getElementById("adresscontent").innerHTML = street + "<br>" + house_number + "<br>" + city + "<br>" + postcode + "<br>"  + country
```

Comment: You welcome. Please mark the solution to indicate that the question is properly answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
street + "<br>" + house_number + "<br>"
```

with innerHTML, you can input HTML codes like HTML pages.

So you can use `<br>` tag with innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

you can use backticks like so

```
document.getElementById('adresscontent').innerText= `${street} 
  ${house_number} 
  ${city} 
  ${postcode} 
  ${country}
`;
```